# sql server bulk insert nulls into time column

Tags: sql, sql-server, nullable, bulkinsert

I'm having trouble inserting null value from a bulk insert statement.

Two columns are nullable and the Id is identity.

The `int` nullable workd out fine, but the `time` doesn't.

- Here the bulk statement:

  ```
  BULK INSERT Circulation 
  FROM '.....file.cs' 
  WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2, MAXERRORS = 0, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
       ROWTERMINATOR = '', KEEPNULLS)
  ```
- Here is an extract of the csv:

  ```
  ID, IDStopLine, IDException, Hour, PositionHour, Day

  ,28, 8, 12:20, 52, 0

  ,29, 163, , 1,
  ```

Meaning that I'm trying to insert nulls in those both columns. The result is ithe int column with NULL and the time column with 00:00:00

[image]

Comment: that's not even a bulk insert statement, the example uses a SP with the "insert" "values" nomenclature

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why time column insert with 00:00:00, but if you need NULL then it is possible to try create trigger and run BULK INSERT with FIRE_TRIGGER argument

```
CREATE TRIGGER dateNull ON dbo.Circulation
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.Circulation(IdStopline, IdException, Hour, PositionHour, Day) 
  SELECT IdStopline, IdException, NULLIF(Hour, '00:00:00.0000000'), PositionHour, Day FROM inserted
END      

BULK INSERT dbo.Circulation 
FROM 'you_file.csv' 
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, 
      MAXERRORS = 0, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', KEEPNULLS, FIRE_TRIGGERS)
```

Answer (score 1):

*To insert "NULL" instead of "Default value of Col2", you need to use the -k switch or KEEPNULL option, as demonstrated in the following bcp and BULK INSERT examples.*

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
BULK INSERT MyTestDefaultCol2
   FROM 'C:\MyTestEmptyField2-c.Dat'
   WITH (
      DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      KEEPNULLS
   );
GO
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx